# Copying a function to RAM

Tags: c, memory, embedded, allocation

I am working on a Embedded application which has a power on initialization routine which is followed by a infinite loop which contains resident program(residing in ROM memory) and a remote program(residing in RAM memory). something like below shown code

```
       main()
     {
       por();    // power on initialization
       while(1)
       {
          if(Flag == Resident) // enum Flag{Resident,Remote};
           ResidentProgram();           
          else
            RemoteProgram();   // program which needs to placed in RAM area of memory
       }
      }
```

Here in the por() routine i want to copy the RemoteProgram() in to RAM. later if needed i will call the change to the Flag to Remote. After that i want the program to be executed from RAM location
Here i am not able to place RemoteProgram() function in RAM. kindly help
Using linker scripts we will be able to place the function at desired address only before runtime but not during runtime. here i want to place it during runtime. can anyone help solving this problem. also i dont want to disturb locations occupied by other variables.

Comment: This is entirely down to the platform and toolchain you're using, there is no standard way of expressing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion (from a position of at least some experience) is to do it the way operating systems do it: use a proper object file format, and load it yourself.

You cannot expect to be able to, in C, copy an already-compiled function around, since you won't have access to any basic information about the code in the function (not even its size, much less any relocation information).

So, embed the code as an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) or some other format, and write an ELF loader which can load the data to the desired location. Being "on the inside" of the format will let you properly implement relocation if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs to know where in read only memory your function code is located. One way to do that is to place the code in a 'named section'. Your function needs to be compiled so that it will run correctly at the ram location you are going to copy it to.  So the function has a load location and a runtime location. Then you can write some C code to copy the function code from it's load location to it's runtime location.

Precisely how you do all of this, as has already been said, is platform and tool chain specific.  Here is one method:

C Source code:

```
#include <string.h>

void copy_code_to_ram()
{
    extern char _my_code_in_ram_start_space[];
    extern char _my_code_in_ram_end_space[];
    extern char _my_code_in_ram_start[];
    memcpy(_my_code_in_ram_start, _my_code_in_ram_start_space, _my_code_in_ram_end_space - _my_code_in_ram_start_space);
}

int i;

#pragma code_seg("my_code_in_ram")

void function_in_sram()
{
    i++;
}

#pragma code_seg()

void main()
{
    copy_code_to_ram();
    function_in_sram();
    while (1);
}
```

Linker script extracts:

```
MEMORY
{
    rom:    origin = 0XFFF00000, length = 0X100000
    ram:    origin = 0X00000000, length = 0X800000
}

SECTIONS
{
    ____CODE :
    {
        <additional script here>
        __my_code_in_ram_start_space = .;
        . += sizeof(my_code_in_ram);
        __my_code_in_ram_end_space = .;
    } > rom

    __my_code_in_ram LOAD(__my_code_in_ram_start_space) :
    {
        __my_code_in_ram_start = .;
        *(my_code_in_ram)
        __my_code_in_ram_end = .;
    } > ram
    <additional script here>
}
```

A video which shows a toolchain specific way of generating this C code and linker script might be useful:

http://www.crossware.com/coldfire/CCodeInRamVideo